# Direct memory access to Cypress CYW43455 wireless LAN chip

Tags: wifi, kernel, driver, hotspot

Where can I find the direct memory addresses or GPIO pinouts for directly controlling the Cypress CYW43455 Wi-Fi chip on the Raspberry Pi Zero W from a custom unikernel, or a modified Raspbian?

My goal is to advertise a (non-working) WiFi hotspot from the Raspberry Pi Zero using no pre-packaged kernel drivers, either by booting from a custom unikernel or from Raspbian, but with all Kernel wifi modules disabled.

After I get that working, I'll look into ARP negotiation.

(Please don't ask me why I want to do this or try to convince me to use existing drivers - I want to write my own and I'm crazy enough to want to try.)

Comment: Soo why do you want to this? Wouldn't you rather use the existing drivers?

Comment: The wifi chip is connected through SDIO (GPIO34-39)

Comment: If you have finished it please make a self answered question to tell how it works. I'm very interested in it because I also have problems with the existing drivers used for an access point together with a client connection and used for an encrypted ad hoc wifi network.